# What would a transaction between two parties who unknowingly use XLM look like?

Tags: transactions

What would be the mechanisms or applications needed to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Stellar offer [Payment Paths](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/path.html)

You can use [PathFinding](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/path-finding.html) to search for "best" conversion path between origin and destination asset. It uses Stellar Decentralized Exchange for "internal currency trading"

Answer (score 1):

With tools currently in production, I imagine you could buy something from someone with your currency, and the seller would receive the same amount in their currency. The tool/application uses Lumens as a bridge/currency converter. i.e. USD-->LUMENS-->PESOS. The Lumens are the pipe/channel/conversion mechanism. In the example, you can replace "USD" & "PESOS" with any currency, or store of value (pigs?), set-up as an asset/trustine on the Stellar system.

Comment: Which “tools currently in production” are you referring to?